# GWT pattern for handling mobile browsers

Tags: gwt

I am working on a GWT app that needs to serve a different layout to mobile device users. I can easily determine if a user is using a mobile browser; however, I'm not sure about the best pattern for handling them.

I am currently using the MVP pattern - would it be best to simply pass a browser-specific view to the Presenter or is there a more appropriate method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up GWT to detect the web browser used, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166554/detecting-mobile-browser-in-gwt). Then, via [Deferred Binding](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html), let the compiler "slip" the correct view into place for the, say, `mobilesafari` user agent. That way, you won't have to litter your Java code with browser detection, etc.

Comment: Perfect, I did not think about using deferred binding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done it is to have different GWT modules (with their own entrypoint, Gin modules, even different CssResources) and then on the myapp.html page you just have to check out what browser is requesting the content and based on it (javascript checks) the appropriate module

```
<script src="myapp/myapp.nocache.js"/>
```

or

```
<script src="mymobileapp/mymobileapp.nocache.js"/>
```

is loaded.

If you are working with GIN and an MVP framework ([gwt-platform](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP) is my platform of choice) you can then reuse the code that was already written for the presenters and only implement different views.