# determine if the device on which browser is running in gwt bootstrap

Tags: gwt, web-applications, gwt-bootstrap

Is their any way in gwt or gwt bootstrap to find the device on which the web app is running.
Like if the device is iphone,tablet,desktop.ipad etc.,Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need bootstrap at all to know which browser your client is running on.

Just call...

```
Navigator.getUserAgent()
```

...to get the user-agent of the browser.

A list of all user-ager avaiable is provided here:

http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/All/

For instance, check for "ipad" match in user-agent String.

Comment: the Navigator.getUserAgent().indexof("ipad") always gives me -1

Comment: check the list, in some browsers it is "ipad" in others is "iPad". Do the match in lowercase.

Comment: Nop i tried with String ua =  Navigator.getUserAgent.toLowerCase().

Comment: which user agent do you get?

Comment: Desktop user Agent  - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36 . I got the same user agent property for android phone and iphone.

Comment: Are you using chrome with "desktop mode" enable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295189/chrome-for-ios-user-agent-on-ipad

Answer (score 2):

### Setup

GWT allows you to define properties which will be resolved during the execution of the deferred binding mechanism (part of the startup sequence of your app, see *Elements of Deferred Binding* [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules)). For example, defining this in your app's `gwt.xml` file:

```
<define-property name="formfactor" values="desktop,tablet,mobile" />
```

And then supplying this in the same file:

```
<property-provider name="formfactor">
  <![CDATA[
    // my User Agent String-parsing JavaScript code 
  ]]>
</property-provider>
```

For a full example, see [MobileWebApp](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/mobilewebapp), a GWT sample app. Specifically, take a look at [FormFactor.gwt.xml](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/mobilewebapp/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/sample/mobilewebapp/FormFactor.gwt.xml).

### Usage

Once you set up your property and program its provider, there are multiple places in your app where you can reach the value of the property:

- CSS:

  ```
   @if formfactor mobile {
     /* my mobile form factor-specific rules */
   }
  ```

  (for more supported rules see [CssResource](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/resources/client/CssResource.html))
- In the [module XML definition](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml) (e.g. for ClientFactory selection):

  ```
  <replace-with class="com.my.client.ClientFactoryImplDesktop">
    <when-type-is class="com.my.client.ClientFactory" />
    <when-property-is name="formfactor" value="desktop" />
  </replace-with>
  ```
- Java code? [Only via deferred binding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17748136/282176).

Comment: Thank u for the reply. Can u please tell me how do i get the values in ui side. Im using uibinder . cause every time i do Navigator.getUserAgent() .indexof("desktop") even on desktop i get -1

Comment: Everything I mentioned so far happens UI-side. I expanded the answer with some usage scenarios.