# Accessing a module-defined property from Java code

Tags: gwt

When expanding [an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17725095/282176) I realized I don't know if it is possible to access a module-defined property from Java code. For example, if I have:

```
<define-property name="formfactor" values="desktop,tablet,mobile" />
```

Is something available in the SDK to go like this?

```
String ff = [someClass].getProperty("formfactor")`?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use deferred-binding.

The easiest way is to use `<replace-with>` rules, but it requires quite a lot of boilerplate code (one per value, with classes that return the same value as the property from a getter)

Or you could use a generator and `<generate-with>` rule.

In any case, you'll need an interface or base class to use in your code and whose exact implementation (either hand-coded or generated) will be switched using deferred binding rules.